# Using Elastic Search to identify failed logins

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I have a certain use case that I'm researching involving creating a query that returns events whenever a failed login occurs from two separate accounts on one machine.

I've created the following query, but I'm receiving errors whenever I try to run it.

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
       "query": {
            "match_all": {}
       },
       "filter" : {
           "term": {
              "EventID": "4625"
           }
       },
       "filter" : {
            "range" : { 
                "_timestamp" : { 
                    "gt": "now-15m"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
aggs: {
    group_by_host: {
        terms: {
            field: 'hostname'
        },
        aggs: {
            group_by_user: {
                terms: {
                    field: 'username'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your filters inside `bool`. You can refer to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) for more info.

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "EventID": "4625"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "_timestamp": {
                  "gt": "now-15m"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_host": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hostname"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_user": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "username"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that query, but i got this in return: took         : 244103
timed_out    : False
_shards      : @{total=199; successful=199; failed=0}
hits         : @{total=0; max_score=; hits=System.Object[]}
aggregations : @{group_by_host=}

Comment: it means query did not match any document and hence zero results